# Best practice Objects from SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I tried searching but couldn't find a proper answer.
I am creating an application that contains a lot of different objects. The data for these objects is saved in an MSSQL database. What is the best way to get data out?

For simplicity I will use two objects here:
ItemObject
UserObject

Both of them has a constructor which will get data from the Database:

```
public ItemObject(int ID) //same one for UserObject
{
    //Code to get the data from the database for this particular item
}
```

ItemObject has a property called CreatedBy which is a UserObject.

Now the question is what is the best way to create the ItemObject?
I have two possible solutions:

Solution #1:

```
public ItemObject(int ID)
{
    DataTable dt = dal.GetDataTable("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Items WHERE ID = @ID")
    this.CreatedBy = new UserObject((int)dt.rows[0]["UserID"])
}
```

Solution #2

```
public ItemObject(int ID)
{
    DataTable dt = dal.GetDataTable("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Items INNER JOIN Users ON Items.CreatedBy = Users.ID WHERE Items.ID = @ID")
    this.CreatedBy = new UserObject((int)dt.rows[0]["UserID"], dt.rows[0]["Username"].ToString())
}

public UserObject(int ID, string Username)
{
    this.ID = ID;
    this.Username = Username;
}
```

In solution #1 I ask for data twice but in solution #2 I ask for data once. Although solution #1 is much "cleaner" and easier to read.

Edited after Steves correction.

Comment: You are aware that you can do the select without the crazy slow and memory consuming data table? That really is like "Hey, lets use the worst possible approach".

Comment: I would recommend Entity Framework instead of typing all these queries, I have recently started using it and everything else seems ridiculous now.

Comment: With just this context, you should go for solution #2. It is perfectly clear for me and minimize data access should be a must.

Comment: Imagine that you have 100milion records of items. So I guess users will be far less then that. Then why do you need to access users table on every item record read at all? None of two solutions in this case is good. I would think about option #3 - load users separately and find record when you need to display creator name.

Comment: @Reniuz So you want me to load users into a List in the application and always have it available?

Comment: @TomTom Actually no. I am only aware of Scalars and DataTables. What other option do I have?

Comment: Reading documentation? Entity Framework and hundreds (nearly) other ORMs. DataReader for very slim reading without a data table - which is basic ADO.NET and something everyone leraning it fom the documentation will actually know, as it is the ONLY way to get data out into memory (and all other APIs use it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with solution two. From my point of view solution 1 is not acceptable, though it is "cleaner".
And I think there is no best practice for reading to objects. I like much Entity Framework for this purpose.